# Why is a variable that has the value of an object always up-to-date with the value of the object?

Tags: javascript, variables

I am interested in why, in snippet **B**, `y` is able to capture the value of `x` after `x` has been reassigned when the initialization of `y` occurs *before* the reassignment of `x`.

I have been told the reason is because, in snippet B, `x` is a *reference* data-type - it's value is stored external from the variable/identifier and that variable/identifier just points towards the address of the external memory.

However I could still argue that at the specific 'time' when `y` is being initialized, `x` is still `{5}` so `y` should be `{5}`. There must be something more for me to understand here - perhaps something to do with the order/timing at which JavaScript assigns value to variables...

**A**

```js
x = 5;

y = x;

x = 6;

console.log(x);
console.log(y);
```

**B**

```js
x = {one: 5};

y = x;

x.one = 6;

console.log(x);
console.log(y);
```

Comment: The first one is assignment of a value, and the second is assignment of a reference.

Comment: You are changing the source you are referencing to with `x.one = 6;`

Comment: Since you have a reference and javascript is mutable it will produce that, to avoid it you should dreclare y like this y = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(x))

Comment: @Carlos1232 you could actually apply it as a config to a new object. e.g. `y = {...x}`

Comment: Thanks @Mr.Polywhirl. However, second paragraph shows you I'm aware of this. See my third paragraph.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl yes, that's for es6. not all browsers support it.

Comment: If you debbug the code It show you y = 5 before you assing x to 6.

Comment: @Carlos1232 OK, so use this instead `y = Object.assign({}, x)` instead. You do not need to support IE anymore... even Edge has moved to Chromium and this code works in Edge before they switched anyways. Stop living in the past.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript by reference vs. by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605640/javascript-by-reference-vs-by-value)

Comment: Thanks @sp00m. See my third paragraph - my question is really how is JS able to 'go back' to y and continually update it to the new value of `x`. Obviously, JS must initialise variables at the very end when everything's been read, or something...

Comment: @tonitone110 There isn't such as "going back to update the other variables": whether you doing `x.one = 6` or `y.one = 6`, you're modifying (aka mutating) the same single _value_, `x` and `y` are just two _references_ pointing to it.

Comment: @sp00m I think I get it now. I confused myself because I was expecting `y` to log out `{one: 5}` but the `console.log(y)` occurs after `x` has mutated the object. If it occurred before the mutation it would've logged out like I expected. However your explanations about references has really solidified the concept for me - so thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well... tldr; javascript is kinky!

In essence, on your first snippet:

```
Assign value of, x = 5;
Assign value of, y = x, which holds a reference to the primitive value 5, so y is now directly 5, not x's reference.
Assign value of, x = 6, direct value again, removes the previous correlation with x and y.
```

The above happens because your assignment is involving primitive types.
When you say y=x, you are assigning the primitive 5 to y, not a reference to x, exactly because X holds a primitive, not an object.

On the other hand, your 2nd case involves objects, which are passed by reference instead.

So making changes "here" actually effects all references pointing to "here"

```
x = {one : 5}
y = x -> This now is an assignment by passing the reference value, i.e Y points to the same object X is pointing.
x.one = 6; -> this will actually effect the same reference Y has
```

To take it a step further, what if we where to now mutate y again?

If we had, on your 2nd example, this line as the last line

```
y = { two : 5}
```

This would not not effect X at all, it would just reassign y with a new completely new object value.

This has to do with how javascript handles references and assignment.
Take a look [here](https://medium.com/@naveenkarippai/learning-how-references-work-in-javascript-a066a4e15600) for a nice starting point of the ref jungle

Comment: Thanks @MKougiouris. See my third paragraph - my question is really how is JS able to 'go back' to `y` and continually update it to the new value of `x`?

Comment: ok, so then for your main question now:
Because based on what we said, you are not "re-assigning y OR x" you are just mutating 1 field from X.
So y is referencing X, and you can mutate properties from it.
But the moment you say y = {some: thing} the "reference" is broken, and y is its own man

Comment: I think I get it now. I confused myself because I was expecting `y` to log out `{one: 5}` but the `console.log(y)` occurs after `x` has mutated the object. If it occurred before the mutation it would've logged out like I expected. However your explanations about references has really solidified the concept for me - so thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In snippet B, `y` is **also** a reference. It points exactly to the same place as `x` does. You have 2 references to the same object.

So after declaring `y = x`, modifying the value of `x.one` or `y.one` is exactly the same thing.
[image]

Comment: Thanks @dgiugg. I'm aware `y` is also a reference. See my third paragraph - my question is really how is JS able to 'go back' to `y` and continually update it to the new value of `x`?

Comment: It does not "go back". It is not the "value of `x`". There is one object, independent from `x` and `y`. There are 2 references, `x` and `y`, pointing at that same object. Changing that object by calling it `x` or `y` is strictly equivalent.

Comment: I think I get it now. I confused myself because I was expecting `y` to log out `{one: 5}` but the `console.log(y)` occurs after `x` has mutated the object. If it occurred before the mutation it would've logged out like I expected. However your explanations about references has really solidified the concept for me - so thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A nice (truncated) excerpt from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_sharing:

> If a variable was passed [to a function], *it is not possible to simulate an assignment* on that variable in the callee's scope. However, since the function has access to the same object as the caller (no copy is made), *mutations to those objects within the function are visible* to the caller.